# how to optimize time of this python script Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, optimization, pandas-groupby

I have script which I need to optimize. The sample data is added here [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rr1oHhr8tHnZR0aFU7ljlxF45hyDL2f5/view?usp=sharing).

I have tried several things changing groupby to using sort values. I have tried swifter to make apply fast but instead it is taking more time.

```
df_loop = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")

df_loop.index = df_loop["Destination"]

uni_list = df_loop["Destination"].unique()

def get_custcon(x):
    dfa = df_loop[(df_loop.index.isin(x))]
    dfa.sort_values\
    (by = ["Source","Time"],ascending=True).drop_duplicates('Source'\
                                            ,keep='first',inplace = True)
    return  [x,dfa["con"].sum()/dfa["Options"].sum()]



def get_optimisation(site):
    list_site = []
    for si in range(site):
        s = "step_" + str(si) 
        list_site.append(s)
    list_site = ["random_combination"] + list_site + ["Cust"] 
    test_data = pd.DataFrame(columns = list_site)
    Iteration = 1 #how many iteration do you want to run 
    for it in range(Iteration):
        test_list = []
        random_com = tuple(random.sample(set(df_loop["Source"]\
                                              .unique()),site)) ### random combination
        test_list.append(random_com)

        for i in range(site):
            li = list(range(site))
            li.remove(i)
            col_dict = {}
            for k in li:
                j = "site_" + str(k)
                if j not in col_dict:
                    col_dict[j] = [random_com[k]]* 5
            df_com = pd.DataFrame(col_dict)
                
            df_com["site_"+str(i)] = uni_list
            df_com["res"] = df_com.apply(lambda x : get_custcon(list(x)),axis = 1)
            df_com[['combination', 'cust_C']] = df_com['res'].apply(pd.Series)
            
            solution = df_com.loc[df_com["cust_C"].idxmin()][["res"]][0]
            random_com  = tuple(solution[0])
            test_list.append(tuple(solution[0]))
        test_list.append(solution[1])
        test_data.loc[it] = test_list
    return(test_data.loc[test_data["Cust"].idxmin()][test_data.columns[-2]])

start = time.time()
print(list(get_optimisation(2))) # write site number here 
end = time.time()
print("time",end - start)
```

This code is typically taking 0.038 seconds. Now the data I have shared is sample only. I have data of 2.5 M rows Where It is taking 75 seconds, But I can't spare this much time for this process.

code I have Tried But no luck:

```
def get_custcon(x):
    dfa = df_loop[(df_loop.index.isin(x))]
    dfa.sort_values('Time').groupby('Source').first()
    return  [x,dfa["con"].sum()/dfa["Options"].sum()]


df_com["res"] = df_com.swifter.apply(lambda x : get_custcon(list(x)),axis = 1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you had a chance to run the profiler to find the hot spot(s)?

Comment: Your code calls `get_optimised_sites()` but that method is not in your post. Is it an alias/typo for `get_optimisation()`?

Comment: Yeah thats a typing mistake. Thanks for Pointing out

Comment: The most time consuming function is get_custcon(). But I have to call it site * len(uni_list) Times

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without reviewing why you are nesting 3 for loops as you have stated that the "slow" part is `get_custcon(x)`.

> **aside**: you might think about if that nesting is required or if there is a way to get your result without 3 nested loops

Looking at `get_custcon(x)` I see that you are repeatedly sorting a filtered result. I think you can sort once and just filter:

```
df_loop_sorted = df_loop.copy()
df_loop_sorted.sort_values(by = ["Source","Time"], ascending=True).drop_duplicates('Source', keep='first', inplace = True)

def get_custcon(x):
    dfa = df_loop_sorted[(df_loop_sorted["Destination"].isin(x))]
    return  [x,dfa["con"].sum()/dfa["Options"].sum()]
```

This change cuts the execution time in half for small data. It might be much more significant for larger data.

Note that depending on the data you might need to:

```
drop_duplicates(['Destination', 'Source'], keep='first', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts. now it is taking just 57 seconds in my main data set. I am still looking at different possibility and logically I have to do  .drop_duplicates('Source', keep='first', inplace = True)  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

### original answer

I want to draw your attention to the fact that some of the code in both versions of your `get_custcon` function runs without effect.

In the example of your second function. You instantiate dfa in the first line, but then your sort/groupby/first runs without being saved.

```
def get_custcon(x):
    dfa = df_loop[(df_loop.index.isin(x))]
    dfa.sort_values('Time').groupby('Source').first() # <-- this runs for nothing
    return  [x,dfa["con"].sum()/dfa["Options"].sum()]
```

You could comment the `dfa.sort_values…` line and get the exact same result. This might be further hidden by the fact than in the provided dataset, there is no case where `Source` values are duplicated for a given `Destination`.

*If would be easier to address your question if you were providing a better toy dataset (with edge cases), and briefly explain what you try to achieve.*

### edit to address your comment:

> In the get_custcon function in sort values line I have used inplace = True. so that I don't need to save that sorted dataframe again in a variable.

This is not the case are you are not performing the `inplace` operation on the `dfa` dataframe, but on a copy.

See for instance the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[3,2], [1,1], [2, 2], [2, 4], [4, 1]], columns=['A', 'B'])
df
```

This prints out the following:

```
    A   B
0   3   2
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   2   4
4   4   1
```

Let's apply the `drop_duplicate` function, in place, and check the content of `df`:

```
df.drop_duplicates('A', inplace=True)
df
```

This yields, as expected:

```
    A   B
0   3   2
1   1   1
2   2   2
4   4   1
```

However, if you apply first another function, such as `sort_values`, you obtain a copy of `df` and this one gets modified by `drop_duplicates` in place. Neither operation is "saved" in the original `df`. See for yourself:

```
df.sort_values(by='A').drop_duplicates('A', inplace=True)
df
```

that outputs the unmodified `df`.

If you want to keep all chained changes, you should do something like:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='A').drop_duplicates('A')
df
```

which gives us, as expected:

```
    A   B
1   1   1
2   2   2
0   3   2
4   4   1
```

Comment: In the get_custcon function in sort values line I have used inplace = True. so that I don't need to save that sorted dataframe again in a variable.

Comment: In your first `get_custon` function, you run the `inplace=True` on a copy of dfa, so this has no effect on dfa itself.

Comment: I updated my answer to address the `inplace` comment. Could you please elaborate on the purpose of the original code? This would be helpful to optimize it.

Comment: This doesn't make any difference in terms of time for me but thanks for your help

Comment: Well, it was not supposed to improve anything, I just pointed out that you had an error in your original code. Now I am confident that one can find an improvement to your code. However, it is not clear to me what you want to achieve. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve with your computation?

Comment: Basically I want to improve time, I have shared data as well for this code and other details as mentioned in question.

Answer (score 1):

A few observations:
The code looks like a travelling salesman type problem being solved inside it. Because of the limited scope to understand the context, I can't really suggest, but it seems that you could use parallel processing on the uni_list. i.e. rewrite the code in such a way that we only check for one site to start with, and check all the paths including that and so on. If you can do that, then your time will scale down from O(site*uni_list) to O(site) or so.
A minor code optimization could be done taking out the
`setsource = set(df_loop["Source"].unique())` part out from the loop. For a small dataset, it doesn't lead to significant changes, but maybe you can check for the bigger dataset.
Also, as I take a deeper look into get_custcon(x); it calculates the sum of con and options for a fixed number of possibilities.
A better idea will be to run this function once for all possibilities, and then use a fixed dictionary of the values when we actually call it.
This will reduce the processing time in low number of sites. To be more accurate, you will call the get_custcon `iteration*sites*uni_list` times. Now, in memorization, you call it (uni_list choose sites) times. You can choose the better process based on your practical application.
Also, I would check how the data is being read. Sometimes, reading excel file takes a significant time; and 2.5M data points would end up taking quite a lot of time in such a case. So if that's the case, you would look into better solutions such as hdf or feather files.

Comment: about setsource = set(df_loop["Source"].unique()). I will need a random point to start with in every new iteration. This iteration number could be anything from 1-30 and setting source outside will not give me random source every time.  I have already implemented Multi processing for first for loop, which is running over range(Iteration) by which I am saving a lot of time. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I am not asking you to put the random_com = random.sample(setsource, sites) outside the loop. you will be keeping only the setsource outside, and but the random.sample will be still inside. Shouldn't that provide you the needed randomness?

Comment: alright, yeah understood. Thanks this will help a little.